# smarty assign property work in ps 1.6 but not in 1.7 version

Tags: prestashop

i would like to assign variables and make them appear in the both versions but the variables appears only on the 1.6 one, here is my code:

```
$smarty = $this->context->smarty;
$smarty->assign('dimension',$dimension);
$smarty->assign('path',$path);
```

and the tpl file content :

```
<img src="{$path}" width="{$dimension}" height="{$dimension}" />
```

i verified those variables appear in the log files

Comment: What is the context? Front controller? Module? Admin controller? PS 1.7 is full of examples about using smarty->assign

Comment: i am using it inside a hook, hookDisplayPDFInvoice @FranCerezo

Comment: You should add {debug} in related template and watch if variables exist. Maybe these exist, but template flow is taking a wrong bifurcation and shows results you do not expect.

Comment: i told in my question that i succeeded to show all variables i want to assign through smarty

Comment: Then i do not understand your problem.

Comment: it seems you did not get me, i say i can show these variables in log files not in my tpl files. so the variables i want to assign through smarty are real

Answer (score 1):

You should have your module check if it's a PS1.6 or 1.7 because the pdf generation works slightly different.

In PS1.7 you can assign variables, but they won't be rendered because of the pdf rendering engine. I think it should look something like this:

```
public function hookDisplayPDFInvoice($hookArgs)
{
    if ((bool)version_compare(_PS_VERSION_, '1.7.0.0', '<=')) {
        $smarty = $this->context->smarty;
        $smarty->assign('dimension', $dimension);
        $smarty->assign('path', $path);
    } else {
        $hookArgs['object']->path = 'path';
        $hookArgs['object']->dimension = 'dimension';
    }
}
```